# Spark Window function - Get all records in a partition in each row, with order maintained

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

My Input table ('messages'):

```
sessionID  timestamp  sender   message
S1         1          BUYER    Hi
S1         2          AGENT    Tell me Sir
S1         3          BUYER    Can you help me?
S1         4          BUYER    Sure.
S2         3          AGENT    Hello Sir
S2         2          BUYER    Hello.
```

My desired output:

```
sessionID  timestamp  sender   message             conversation     
S1         1          BUYER    Hi                  [[BUYER : Hi], [AGENT : Tell me Sir], [BUYER : Can you help me?], [BUYER : Sure.]]
S1         2          AGENT    Tell me Sir         [[BUYER : Hi], [AGENT : Tell me Sir], [BUYER : Can you help me?], [BUYER : Sure.]]
S1         3          BUYER    Can you help me?    [[BUYER : Hi], [AGENT : Tell me Sir], [BUYER : Can you help me?], [BUYER : Sure.]]
S1         4          BUYER    Sure.               [[BUYER : Hi], [AGENT : Tell me Sir], [BUYER : Can you help me?], [BUYER : Sure.]]
S2         3          AGENT    Hello Sir           [[BUYER : Hello], [AGENT : Hello Sir]]
S2         2          BUYER    Hello               [[BUYER : Hello], [AGENT : Hello Sir]]
```

My query:

```
spark.sql("select *, collect_list( concat(sender, ' : ', message) ) over (partition by sessionID order by timestamp asc) as conversation from messages")
```

Current output:

```
sessionID  timestamp  sender   message             conversation     
S1         1          BUYER    Hi                  [[BUYER : Hi]]
S1         2          AGENT    Tell me Sir         [[BUYER : Hi], [AGENT : Tell me Sir]]
S1         3          BUYER    Can you help me?    [[BUYER : Hi], [AGENT : Tell me Sir], [BUYER : Can you help me?]]
S1         4          BUYER    Sure.               [[BUYER : Hi], [AGENT : Tell me Sir], [BUYER : Can you help me?], [BUYER : Sure.]]
S2         3          AGENT    Hello Sir           [[BUYER : Hello]]
S2         2          BUYER    Hello               [[BUYER : Hello], [AGENT : Hello Sir]]
```

As can be noticed from the current and desired outputs, I want the order of messages maintained in collect list, and I also need all records in every partition to be included (not just the rows till the current record)
Can someone help me get the desired output?

Best Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a specification for the window, as shown in capital letters below. This will ensure all rows in the partition are included.

```
spark.sql("""
select *,
  collect_list( concat(sender, ' : ', message) ) over (
    partition by sessionID
    order by timestamp asc
    ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING
  ) as conversation from messages
""")
```